# What does Philosopher mean in the first Harry Potter book?

Tags: harry-potter

What does Philosopher mean in Britain? Obviously it's not the American meaning or the book & movie wouldn't have changed the title for the USA.

Comment: The [Philosopher's Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher%27s_stone)

Comment: If you want to accept an answer, you can by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: Just to answer the English language portion of the question. The word philosopher does not have regional variations, it means a thinker, everywhere. The word 'philosopher' is not a British variant of the word 'sorcerer'. The change in titles actually does change the meaning.

Comment: The question should include the book and movie title. In many country, the title was not changed. When the question is about Book title "Harry Potter and the **Philosopher**'s Stone" vs Movie title "Harry Potter and the **Sorcerer**'s Stone".

Answer (score 60):

As per Valorum's comment, the [Philosopher's Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher%27s_stone) is a legendary alchemical item.

> The philosopher's stone, more properly philosophers' stone or stone of the philosophers (Latin: lapis philosophorum) is a legendary alchemical substance capable of turning base metals such as mercury into gold (chrysopoeia, from the Greek χρυσός khrusos, "gold", and ποιεῖν poiēin, "to make") or silver. It is also called the elixir of life, useful for rejuvenation and for achieving immortality; for many centuries, it was the most sought goal in alchemy. The philosophers' stone was the central symbol of the mystical terminology of alchemy, symbolizing perfection at its finest, enlightenment, and heavenly bliss. Efforts to discover the philosophers' stone were known as the Magnum Opus ("Great Work").

It's worth noting that there's some debate as to how literal the "turning lead into gold" goal was, or if alchemy was a more, well, philosophic life approach of self-improvement with turning lead into gold being a metaphor.

Why did they change it? [Because the publisher's didn't think kids would understand the reference](https://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question60594.html).

> The title of the movie was changed to "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone" because the book's name was also changed to this. JK Rowling agreed to change the title of the book from "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone" to "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone" because the publishers thought that American readers wouldn't pick up a book called "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone" because they would associate the word Philosopher with some old, boring guy and not with magic. The word Sorcerer brings magis to mind for American children. ([citation](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-18387,00.html))

Comment: ... To the detriment of those who do know what the philosopher’s stone is. I read the American English version and it wasn’t until months later (when I happened to see the British English title) that I had a two-blink “*ooh?... OOOOOHHH*” moment. (yes, I realize I was not their main age demographic)

Comment: @EuroMicelli - Well, that's exactly the point. While that's true, vanishingly few of said people are the 7-9 year old kids that book was targeted at. And if they hadn't picked up and loved the book in huge numbers here in the US, likely most of us old codgers wouldn't have heard of it.

Comment: @EuroMicelli Similarly, when I read the book I wondered why they titled with Sorcerer when the item was obviously based on the well known Philosopher's Stone.   It was considerably later that I came across the original name though.

Comment: Interesting, I believe there is a common misconception (that I also believed) that it was named "Sorcerer's Stone" in the US due to a previous trademark or something.

Comment: "*Because the publisher's didn't think kids would understand the reference.*" I think this question here is evidence of somebody from the US not understanding the reference. So, I suppose the publishers did have some point.

Comment: It's even more confusing because *philosopher* has a somewhat different meaning now than when alchemy was a hot subject in Western Europe. Back then someone who studied what we would now call science would have been termed something like *natural philosopher*. Now it refers to an almost entirely different field of study, and if kids didn't know *philosopher's stone* the book might have seemed much less intriguing. Anyways, it's hard to suggest the US publishers made a bad choice, given the book's popularity.

Comment: @VLAZ Although, considering that the book goes on to explain what the Philosopher's Stone is, and what it can do, changing the name of a known historical myth to something different does the people who *don't* know the reference a disservice too. It'd be like the book describing a way to dislodge food when someone's choking, and the Publishers calling it the "Henry Move", because they think "Heimlich Maneuver" is too complicated to pronounce.  Instead of a minor moment of education and real-world historical knowledge, you instead set them up to potentially look like fools later in life...

Comment: The source for that link is the opionion section of the guardian. On the same page they propose other theories - including '"Sorceror" sounds exciting, "philosopher" sounds boring'

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106864/discussion-on-answer-by-fuzzyboots-what-does-philosopher-mean-in-the-first-harry).

Answer (score 22):

The word *philosopher* itself means the same thing (or rather, things) on both sides of the pond. The issue was that the American publisher thought that people would not know what "philosopher's stone" (i.e. the whole phrase) meant. They decided that "sorcerer's stone" would be a better term to use, because even if you've never heard of such a thing, you know it has to do with magic. With "philosopher's stone", if you don't know that it's the alchemists' Holy Grail (and the word "philosopher" itself should really be interpreted as "alchemist"), you can't place it in any context, so you might conclude that it's something to do with actual philosophy. And what child wants to read about philosophy?

Comment: "Philosopher" in this context ***doesn't*** mean what the conventional modern meaning means.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying, @Valorum.

Comment: @Valorum: the questioner looked at the change in the title and came to the completely incorrect conclusion that word "philosopher" must mean something different in British English. This is emphatically not true: the word "philosopher" carries **exactly the same meanings** (note plural) in both flavors of English.

Comment: But not in its original context is the point that I was trying to make.

Comment: Either I'm not understanding your point, or you're wrong: the word "philosopher" in "philosopher's stone" means alchemist, which is 100% one of the meanings of the word "philosopher". It's not a meaning that the word "philosopher" can't have in any other context.

Comment: but Martha, the context is useless if you don't understand it the entire term "philosopher's stone" to begin with, in which case, many people would assume "Harry Potter and the Deep Thinker's Rock" - wth is that?

Comment: @NKCampbell: ... which is exactly what I'm saying, and exactly why the title was changed... ?

Comment: "And what child wants to read about philosophy?", well, perhaps they forgot that [Sofie's World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie%27s_World) has been internationally translated as a well-known children's book (age 10+, roughly or even below the demographic as HP). Kids do actually read about philosophy, albeit on their own level.

Comment: Everyone in this conversation is agreeing with each other. "Philosophers's stone" is a pre-existing term. Philosopher means "alchemist" here. Philosopher means something else in other contexts. This usage is international. Some people omitted some of these statements in their posts but no one is contradicting them. Now let's all smile and think about how smart our conversation mates are.

Comment: 'Philosopher' meaning 'alchemist' is not familiar to the majority of USA citizens. Calling it the "Philosopher's stone" in the USA, would be as odd to most Americans as calling it "the History Professor's Stone". It should've been localized as "the Alchemist's Stone", IMO.

Comment: Alchemy, like any other science, was considered part of philosophy at one time.

Comment: Thankfully, there are many languages where that legendary artifact has a name using the same word as the Magi (or three wise men) who visited baby Jesus, so there is a lot less chance for confusing it with philosophy.

Answer (score 14):

In the context of "Philosopher's Stone", a philosopher is a scientist (in medieval usage, a natural scientist -- as opposed to, say, a mathematician) -- specifically, an *alchemist*.  The Philosopher's Stone is the ultimate goal of alchemy, giving the ability to perform any transmutation, as well providing an Elixir of Life that confers immortality.

More broadly, "philosopher" is made up of two Greek roots: "philos" -- love (non-sexual, brotherly), and "sophias" -- wisdom.  A philospher, then is someone who loves wisdom.  Historically, the primary occupation of philosphers was to engage in reasoned argument with the intention of discerning truth from supposition -- earning their name by determining what was, in fact, "wisdom" (as opposed to supposition, speculation, and so forth).

Comment: You might want to stress that the word philosopher used to mean 'natural scientist' rather than 'sits around debating the nature of existence'

Comment: To the Greeks, there wasn't much difference -- they were theorists, not experimentalists.

Comment: Philosophers in ancient times would experiment with optics, chemistry, natural sciences, etc. Even those who were engaged in argument were thrashing out what we'd refer to as the social sciences.

Comment: @Valorum The Trivium vs. the Quadrivium.  In ancient and even mdeival times, "philosopher" was an extremely broad word, but experiment wasn't the core of philosophy even in the early Iron Age -- it was just something smart people tended to do, because they were also intensely curious about the world.

Comment: Mathematicians were also philosophers. There's the whole school of platonism...

Comment: "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, Than are dreamt of in your philosophy." - as recently as Shakespeare "philosophy" meant science or learning generally and it was well understood by his audience.

Comment: Minor point: *sophos* = "skill, learning, wisdom", not "to argue".

Comment: Yes, please correct that. A philosopher is one who loves wisdom ("sophia"), knowledge. One who is wise ("sophos"). It has nothing to do with arguing. See https://www.etymonline.com/word/philosopher.